# how create a eventdispatcher object

Tags: javascript

Is possible to create a object that can dispatch events just like HTMLElements and use it as prototype of new classes mine?

I know I can write a EventDispatcher class to make that for me, but I believe it is slower than using native functions who already do that (addEventListener, removeEventListener, dispatchEvent).

Case 1:

```
var obj = new EventDispatcher();
obj.addEventListener( 'someevent', listener ); // obj can receive listener to a event

obj.dispatchEvent( myEvent ); // CustomEvent being dispatched
```

Case 2:

```
var MyNewClass = function(){};
// MyNewClass now can dispatch events in their instances...
MyNewClass.prototype = Object.create( EventDispatcher.prototype );

var obj2 = new MyNewClass();
obj2.addEventListener( 'someevent', listener ); // works!
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to dispatch DOM events?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use native (DOM)Events.

Use [`document.createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent)

And `element.dispatchEvent(my_event);`